# Spark not serializable issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, dependency-injection

I'm, working on refactoring our code so that we can use the CAKE pattern for DI.

I've stumbled upon a serialisation issue which I'm having difficulty in understanding.

When I call this function:

```
def getAccounts(winZones: Broadcast[List[WindowsZones]]): RDD[AccountDetails] = {
  val accounts = getAccounts //call to db

  val result = accounts.map(row =>
    Some(AccountDetails(UUID.fromString(row.getAs[String]("")),
      row.getAs[String](""),
      UUID.fromString(row.getAs[String]("")),
      row.getAs[String](""),
      row.getAs[String](""),
      DateUtils.getIanaZoneFromWinZone(row.getAs[String]("timeZone"), winZones))))
    .map(m=>m.get)
  result
}
```

it works perfectly, but this is ugly and I want to refactor it so that the middle mapping from row to AccountDetails is placed inside a private function - but when doing that it causes the serialisation issue.

I'd like:

```
def getAccounts(winZones: Broadcast[List[WindowsZones]]): RDD[AccountDetails] = {
  val accounts = getAccounts 

  val result = accounts
    .map(m => getAccountDetails(m, winZones))
    .filter(_.isDefined)
    .map(m => m.get)
  result
}

private def getAccountDetails(row: Row, winZones: Broadcast[List[WindowsZones]]): Option[AccountDetails] = {
      try {
        Some(AccountDetails(UUID.fromString(""),
          row.getAs[String](""),
          UUID.fromString(row.getAs[String]("")),
          row.getAs[String](""),
          row.getAs[String](""),
          DateUtils.getIanaZoneFromWinZone(row.getAs[String]("timeZone"), winZones)))
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          logger.error(s"Unable to set AccountDetails $e")
          None
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated of course, the AccountDetails obj is a case class should that be pertinent.  Also happy to take any other advice on implementing cake or DI with spark in general.  Thanks.

Edit to show structure:

```
trait serviceImpl extends anotherComponent {this: DBA =>
  def Accounts = new Accounts
  class Accounts extends AccountService {
    //the methods above are defined here.
  }
```

Edit to include stacktrace:

```
    17/02/13 17:32:32 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 271.36617 ms
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2039)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:365)
    at FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts.getAccounts(FunnelServiceComponentImpl.scala:24)
    at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:26)
    at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:7)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:7)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts, value: FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts@16b7e04a)
    - field (class: FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts)
    - object (class FunnelServiceComponentImpl$FunnelAccounts$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 26 more
17/02/13 17:32:32 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getAccountDetails` is in your class, Spark will want to serialize your entire `FunnelAccounts` object.  After all, you need an instance in order to use this method.  However, `FunnelAccounts` is not serializable.  Thus it can't be sent off to a worker.

In your case, you should move `getAccountDetails` into a `FunnelAccounts` object, so that you don't need an instance `FunnelAccounts` to run it.

Comment: Hey Joe,   Thanks for that.  You are of course correct, I extracted the function out into an object that resides in the same file jsut to test and it worked fine.
My worry now is that I'm moving too far away from the architectural pattern I was trying to follow:  If I leave it as is then I think I'll have more 'layers' than necessary.  By creating an object I'm reducing the utility of the class.  Although I suppose it would become a pure 'getObjectTypeFromSDb' which would then go to the object to 'retrieveObjectValuesFromRow' which would in turn be used - feels a little too granular.

Comment: Sorry - ran out of characters - was going to ask if you've any experience implementing a DI pattern with a Spark project - there's no UI to speak of so no view.  Just DB and manipulation before storiung values

Answer (score 2):

Where are you defining the functions?

Let's say you are defining them in a class X. If the class is not serializable this would cause your issue.

To solve this you can either make it an object instead or make the class serializable.

Comment: Both the functions are within the same class - I've made the class extend serliasable and it hasn't helped at all.  Making it an object would bring it back in line with how it was before but then I lose the ability to incorporate DI.  

I'm following the cake method if that helps explain my dilemma - I've edited the post with my example structure of the class.

Comment: Do you have the serialization stack?  Should be part of the NotSerializableException stack trace.

Comment: @JoeC - Hi Joe, I've edited the question to include the stacktrace - I've tried extending the affected classes with Serialise and then extended them all - no effect I'm afraid.